# OnClickListener reassign problem - Android

Tags: android, button, listener

I am running into a problem when I try to reassign an OnClickListener.  In the code below, my program runs through the startWorkout() method and each time the button is clicked it calculates whether this is the last run through or not.  If it is the last run through, it calls the lastSet() method.  The lastSet() method is supposed to reasssign the button so that it does a different action but everytime I click it, it does the stuff declared in the startWorkout() method.

When I ran it through a debug mode, stepping through, the program correctly went through the lastSet() method and assigned the listener.  But then it went back to the startWorkout() method and reassigned the listener!  So by the time a user clicked it, the button was back to its original listener instead of the final listener.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
public  void startWorkout() {
    doSet();
    Button doneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.done);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // If this is the last result, calls last(set) instead
            saveResult();
            takeRest(61000, 30000);
        }
    });

}

public void lastSet() {
    // Changes layout (keeps the same button)
    setLayoutTest();
    Button doneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.done);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call Finish Methods

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't see startWorkout() calling lastSet() anywhere. Also, please provide details for saveResult() and setLayoutTest().

Comment: Yeah, I cut the stuff out to make it simpler.  I think I found the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it...I was actually assigning the listener twice... (solved a long time ago, just cleaning up my stackoverflow questions)

If you do this:

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // If this is the last result, calls last(set) instead
        saveResult();
        takeRest(61000, 30000);
    }
});
```

and then this:

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        runMethod2();
    }
});
```

then ONLY the second one (runMethod2() in this case) will run.  Rookie mistake, just be sure to delete (or overwrite) any legacy code.

Comment: Maybe you should explain where it went wrong? Oh and just a note, but by convention, MethodNames should be PascalCase.

Comment: I did explain...I assigned the listener twice, I'm not sure what other explanation is necessary...also, I'm not sure what you are referring to in my method names, I follow the Android convention from the source: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: Oops, sorry, I was still thinking C# (about the naming), you are obviously right.

Comment: About assigning it twice, maybe you could highlight it or quote the part where you assign it (for the second time). As you know, the purpose of Stack Overflow is not only to get answers to your questions, but also to help fellow programmers, so how more precise you are in your answer, how better your answer is.